# Crystal Reports: random generation changes (landscape/portrait/size)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm working on a project that produces quite a few pdf's through Crystal Reports.
The problem I'm facing is quite random. Users are reporting that reports sometimes get generated too small (report scaled down to 70% or so and printed upon the pdf) and also that some reports are being printed in landscape while they were designed in portrait and vice versa.

Anyone have an idea what could cause these random changes in generation? and maybe a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time that we have issues like this with Crystal Reports, it is always related to a printer. The problem is going to be determining which printer or report is causing the problem.

We generate our PDFs either in a service or server, so we can look to the default printer for the user that the generator is running as to be the source of the problems.

If the reports are being generated on end-user machines, then I would look to the user's default printer as the source of the problems.

I have also seen Crystal "remember" the printer that it was designed for unless you explicitly choose the `No Printer (optimize for screen display)` in the Page Setup... dialog while designing the report or set the corresponding option in code prior to generating the report.

Hopefully this will get you headed in the right direction.